# Does Encrypt and Decrypt work for SQL Server database files using c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption

I was encrypting and decrypting the SQL Server database `.mdf` and `.ldf` files after detach and while attaching the decrypted files I was getting the following error message

> The header for file 'C:\DB\Test.mdf' is not a valid database file header. The FILE SIZE property is incorrect  .

Please find my below C# code I was using for `.mdf`, the same applies for my `.ldf` files too

```
private const int KEY_SIZE_BYTES = 32;
private const int IV_SIZE_BYTES = 16; 
private const string  DBFILENAME = @"C:\DB\Test.mdf"; ; 

public void EncryptandDecrypt()
{
        var rand = new Random();

        using (var fs = File.Open(DBFILENAME, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                rand.NextBytes(buffer);
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }

        string key = GenerateRandomKey();
        Encrypt(DBFILENAME, @"C:\DB\temp\Test.mdf", key);
        Decrypt(@"C:\DB\temp\Test.mdf", DBFILENAME, key);
    }

    public string GenerateRandomKey()
    {
        byte[] key = new byte[KEY_SIZE_BYTES];

        using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
        {
            rng.GetBytes(key);
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(key);
    }

    public void Encrypt(string inputFile, string outputFile, string key)
    {
        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        byte[] keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
        byte[] ivBytes = new byte[IV_SIZE_BYTES];

        using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
        {
            rng.GetBytes(ivBytes);
        }

        using (var inputStream = File.Open(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (var outputStream = File.Open(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                outputStream.Write(ivBytes, 0, ivBytes.Length);

                using (var cryptoAlgo = Aes.Create())
                {
                    using (var encryptor = cryptoAlgo.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, ivBytes))
                    {
                        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(outputStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            int count;

                            while ((count = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                cryptoStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Decrypt(string inputFile, string outputFile, string key)
    {
        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        byte[] keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
        byte[] ivBytes = new byte[IV_SIZE_BYTES];

        using (var inputStream = File.Open(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            inputStream.Read(ivBytes, 0, ivBytes.Length);

            using (var outputStream = File.Open(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (var cryptoAlgo = Aes.Create())
                {
                    using (var decryptor = cryptoAlgo.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, ivBytes))
                    {
                        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(inputStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            int count;

                            while ((count = cryptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Ram` are you wanting to encrypt certain fields in the database..? if so SQL Server Supports SHA5 Field encryption.. do a simple google search and I am sure you would find many examples on how to do this..

Comment: That would suggest the decrypted output is corrupt ... trying with a known text file would be a good idea.  Those fixed buffers look iffy.

Comment: The Above code works for .txt files and Images. I am working with SQL Express,and need to protect database files.So I need to apply encryption and decryption for the database files

Comment: I doubt that Encryption and Decryption would corrupt the database files during this process.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this code and it was ok. I think you probably get the wrong file from temp folder or something like that for header exception. if you get the access error when you're putting back the file then you have to set the proper permissions for the decrypted file.

Also you need to remove the following code from your EncryptDecrypt method and test a real database file:

```
    var rand = new Random();

    using (var fs = File.Open(DBFILENAME, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            rand.NextBytes(buffer);
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
```

It makes a dummy file that server can not read.